# template function for different types

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

How can I make a function template which works at least for 
any type, enums, `std::vector<T>`, `std::vector<E>` for an enum `E`?

I tried the following using overload resolution and `enable_if`, but while it works for `int` and `vector<int>`, it fails with `vector<E>` saying it couldn't find a function to call:

```
struct Details
{
    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, T>::type
        get_impl(const std::string& key, T*) const
    {
        return static_cast<T>(get_impl<int>(key, static_cast<int*>(0)));
    }

    template<typename T>
    int get_impl(const std::string& key, int*) const
    {
        return int();
    }

    template<typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::vector<T>>::type
        get_impl(const std::string& key, std::vector<T>*) const
    {
        return std::vector<T>();
    }


    template<typename T>
    std::vector<int> get_impl(const std::string& key, std::vector<int>*) const
    {
        return T();
    }

    template<typename T>
    T getValue(const std::string& key)
    {
        return get_impl<T>(key, static_cast<T*>(0));
    }
};

int main()
{
    enum E {A, B};
    Details details;
    details.getValue<int>(""); // ok
    details.getValue<std::vector<int>>(""); // ok
    details.getValue<std::vector<E>>(""); // error: no matching function
}
```

I have a special overload for `vector<enum>`, why doesn't it work?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What doesn't work? It's unclear to me what the problem is.

Comment: just want to have an generic function witch can return all my served types eq. std::string, int, enums, containers of those types. thats not a problem but when i want also a vector of enums i dont get any success.
so when i try to call details.getValue&lt;std::vector&lt;E&gt;&gt; it cannot compile

Comment: Are you asking what your error message means?

Comment: No i need a solution to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you're not keeping your types straight, and you're mixing and matching providing explicit types and doing template deduction. If you look very carefully at the error message you get, you'll see what's going on.

In the enum case, you're calling:

```
details.getValue<std::vector<E>>("");
```

Which calls:

```
template<typename T>
T getValue(const std::string& key)
{
    return get_impl<T>(key, static_cast<T*>(0));
}
```

Here, `T` is `std::vector<E>`. So far so good. Now, the overload you want to call is:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::vector<T>>::type
    get_impl(const std::string& key, std::vector<T>*) const
```

But you're calling it as`get_impl<T>(...)`. Which means that, when trying to resolve this overload, `T` is `std::vector<E>` and the last argument is a `std::vector<std::vector<E>>*`. So this function template is simply not a candidate - the last argument doesn't match, and even if it did, `std::vector<E>` is not an enum, so the `enable_if` would rule it out.

---

The way to fix it is to keep everything in the deduction world. And while we're there, avoid using null pointers to do tag dispatching on. It's confusing - because now some parts of your code use pointers as pointers, and some just use them as types. We can just make a special type to use as a type:

```
template <typename T> struct tag { };
```

And pass that in:

```
template <typename T>
T getValue(std::string const& key ) {
    return get_impl(key, tag<T>{});
}
```

Note that I'm no longer specifying the type to `get_impl`, it'll be deduced. Now, your enum case is:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::vector<T>>::type
get_impl(const std::string& key, tag<std::vector<T>>) const
```

And this will work. We'd deduce `T` as `E` from the `tag` parameter, like you'd wanted originally, and `E` is an enum, so this works.

Note that even if you're on C++11, alias templates work. So while you don't have access to `std::enable_if_t`, you can still write:

```
namespace xstd {
    template <bool B, typename T>
    using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;
}
```

Which makes all of this stuff easier to read:

```
template<typename T>
xstd::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::vector<T>>
get_impl(const std::string& key, tag<std::vector<T>>) const
```

Comment: C++ template magic is hard.  Excellent analysis and explanation!

Comment: mhh did not solved my problem for me it lokks u do also overload resolution as i did with the pointer cast
i changed to your soulution but it cannot detuct.
im on VS10
code sample at https://www.onlinegdb.com/SkiNWmEpf.
in your solution the tag will be created all the time as argument.
in mine it s just a nullptr cast to the expected type so that the compiler can deduct. this ptr is not used anymore

Comment: @helmi `tag` is an empty type, it doesn't lead to generated code. There are literally no advantages to using a null pointer over `tag`. The code you pasted doesn't work because you're trying to do deduction of a type that you don't even need to deduce, because you just added `template <typename T>` to functions that aren't templates.

Comment: @Barry thanks for help 
u are right declaration of template<typename T> does not make sense on some functions.
but about tag u told me that is should use get_impl(key, tag<T>{}); and here tag<T>{} is created.